# java NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.getCharSet() при использовании wordpress api

Tags: java, wordpress

Используя wp-api-v2-client-java пытаюсь создать post на моем сайте на базе wordpress. Но получаю следующий стек ошибок:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.MediaType.getCharSet()Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.getSupportedMediaTypes(RestTemplate.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:680)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:743)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:507)
at com.afrozaar.wordpress.wpapi.v2.Client.doExchange0(Client.java:919)
at com.afrozaar.wordpress.wpapi.v2.Client.doExchange0(Client.java:925)
at com.afrozaar.wordpress.wpapi.v2.Client.doExchange1(Client.java:944)
at com.afrozaar.wordpress.wpapi.v2.Client.createPost(Client.java:179)
at com.afrozaar.wordpress.wpapi.v2.Client.createPost(Client.java:187)
at com.newsprice.publisher.core.Postman.postToServer(Postman.java:132)
at com.newsprice.publisher.core.PostmanTest.postToServerTest(PostmanTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Мой метод:

```
    public void postToServer(){
    String baseUrl = "https://myurl.com/";
    String username = "user";
    String password = "password";
    final Wordpress client = ClientFactory.fromConfig(ClientConfig.of(baseUrl, username, password, true,true));
    final Post post = PostBuilder.aPost()
            .withTitle(TitleBuilder.aTitle().withRendered("TITLE").build())
            .withExcerpt(ExcerptBuilder.anExcerpt().withRendered("Small text").build())
            .withContent(ContentBuilder.aContent().withRendered("Very very large text").build())
            .build();
    try {
        final Post createdPost = client.createPost(post, PostStatus.publish);
    } catch (PostCreateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Мой pom.xml выглядит следующим образом:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Poject_Name</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.afrozaar.wordpress</groupId>
        <artifactId>wp-api-v2-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.newsprice.publisher.core.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Поиски в интернете привели к тому, что я узнал, что `MediaType.getCharSet` является устаревшим методом, но он используется в `wp-api-v2-client-java`. Решение, которое я увидел, это понизить версию springa, для этого я добавлял в свой pom зависимость

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Однако это не помогло. Пробовал менять версию до 4.3.0 у своего `spring-test`, ошибка осталась. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема, что можно попробовать.

Comment: вместо 4.3.0 попробуйте 4.3.1

Comment: пробовал и 4.3.1. Дело в том, что c 4.3.1 метод getCharSet был заменен на getCharset. Поэтому я и смотрел в сторону более ранних версий

Comment: А spring-web какой версии? попробуйте откатить его до той-же что и spring-core.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот понять не могу, что нужно сделать, чтобы на этом сайте мне ответили на вопрос. Я задал уже 10 вопросов, а ответ получил только один. Один, Карл! Рекламу нужно давать или что вообще?
P.s. готов спорить, сейчас налетят модераторы, которые удалят этот ответ, но на сам вопрос никто из них даже не попробует ответить.. А между прочим, я заметил, что вопросы хотяб с одним (каким угодно) ответом привлекают бОльшее количество пользователей.

Comment: Тебя ещё и забанить за такое могут.. А вот нервничать совершенно не нужно - это не продуктивно и совершенно не помогает решению проблем.

Comment: Да я особо ничего не потеряю, если забанят.